# How do i find a matrix of 150*25 from two vectors such that each vector elements multiply with each element of another vector of dim 1*150 &1*25?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a vector created from linspace between specific numbers and have dimensions of 1*150. Now i want to multiply each element of the above created vector with another vector whose dimension is 1*25. The detail of my code is given below

```
c_p = linspace(1,.3*pi,150);
c = c_p';
C = zeros([150,25]);
for i= 1:1:size(C,1)
wp= c(i);
for n= 1:25
    c_wp(n) =  cos(n*wp);
end
C(i,25)= c_wp;
end
```

The vector is actually a multiple of cosine of length 25 and here wp is the elements of first vector of dimension 1*150. SO by the logic, I must have an output of 150*25 but instead giving me "subscripted assignment dimension mismatch". Any help would be appreciated, as i am new to matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To multiply each element of a row vector `a` with each element of another row vector `b`, we can use linear algebra. We transpose `a` to make it a column vector and then use matrix multiplication:

```
a.' * b
```

That way you don't even need a for loop.

Comment: Also known as the "outer", "dyadic", or "tensor product" of two vectors. :-)